# Centralized backup method recommendation for SMEs with various OSes

Tags: windows, mac, backup

Hi I was wondering what in your opinion is the "best" method for having "everything" backed-up in the following situation.

- We are a SMEs with 10 computers in total.

  - Three of those computers are MACs
  - The rest are windows (1 vista, 4 win7 and 2 XPs)

I'm very open to what the method should be but you should also consider the follwing:

- Very limited resources
- Quite "small" bandwidth (4 MBs for all (download) 0.4 MBs (upload, yep, thats it)- though this might get, a little bit better)

One of the main thing to back up would be the mails, considerations:

- All windows computers use outlook, mainly 2003
- There is one mac that uses outlook too (for mac of course - not 2011 yet)

We also have to backup the files:

- Not a huge amount
- Very few very big files
- Very organizes (by machine)

What I would like is to hear your opinions as to which would be the best method (or combination of methods - preferably one of course) considering.

We are not sure what do we need and I'm open to suggestions, though an online (cloud based applications) would be great, remember the the bandwidth is unbearable.

Last think to consider, it that we would like to do weekly updates (unless the method is very easy of course).

Thanks in advance!! I tried to be as specific as possible, but if anything is needed I'll gladly update, please ask for any clarification needed!

---

Please avoid any answers like upgrade all to windows 7 and throw away your macs :) our's may not be an ideal situation, but it is what it is, and right now, it would be impossible for us to change it for a lot of circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

BackupPC - install it on a Linux box, no need to install software on workstations.

for Windows machines need a share to be created (for example c:\documents and settings)

for Linux and macs - export directories via NFS or via ssh

has web based interface for administering and with detailed statistics/ log files

Comment: Nice option. It takes more work than some other methods, but it's free and very capable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably suggest you look at [CrashPlan Pro](http://b3.crashplan.com/business/).  Ten licenses costs $686 a year (looking at their store right now) but it supports all your platforms and provides unlimited cloud based storage, or you can use it to back up locally - or both.  You're not supposed to use the consumer version ($12 a month or less for 10 computers) for business backups.

They also offer a service where they post you a 1TB drive for you to back up on to and ship to them, kick starting your cloud backup.

As for your bandwidth - consider performing the remote backups out of hours - it does mean leaving the computers on overnight but it also gives you a good time to schedule full AV scans and other such tasks.

I use their consumer version and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: I've never heard of CrashPlan before, but I just read about it on lifehacker.  And I had a thought, download crashplan on your 10 computers and then see it's free "backup to another computer" feature to mirror all of your files to of your computers on site. Once a month copy these files to a external hard drive and take it off site.

Answer (score 0):

Check out an online solution like [Mozy.](http://mozy.com/)